# How to use soong namespaces in order to conditionally compile modules

Tags: c++, makefile, android-soong

I'm in the process of converting an Android.mk file to an Android.bp. The Android.mk file dynamically linked libraries within the /my/example/dir, choosing whether or not to link them based on a conditional using an environmental variable that was set elsewhere. .bp files don't allow for conditionals so I'm trying to replicate this behavior with soong_namespaces.

When I add soong namespaces to directories /my/example/dir/A and /my/example/dir/B, A and B now are no longer being linked, but I'm unclear as to how to make them be linked conditionally. The Soong documentation states:

> If a module belongs to an explicit namespace, it can be referenced from a makefile only after after the name of the namespace has been added to the value of PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES variable.

So within the BoardConfig.mk I conditionally add to PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES either /my/example/dir/A or /my/example/dir/B but neither is being linked after doing so. Am I doing this incorrectly or is this not something soong namespaces can do?

Comment: do you have any code example? please also check [ask]

Answer (score 1):

I believe `PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES` expects relative paths from the root of your tree, rather than the absolute paths you specified.

e.g. if your tree lives at `/my`, you'll set

```
PRODUCT_SOONG_NAMESPACES := example/dir/A
```

Comment: Perhaps add the recommended update as part of your answer to illustrate and to make it better than just a comment.